# Is it possible to define a multi valued DataProperty in OWL2 specifying the different values it should take for a given case?

Tags: owl, protege, owl-api

Im regenerating an ontology to OWL2 using the OWL-API and testing with Protégé.

There are some concepts that are subclass of many superclasses, and some DataProperties that should take multiple values, for example:

***Artifactual Location & Artifactual Area***

And I want to specify that:

•   For *Artifactual Location*  the DataProperty *hasConcreteEntityType* should take the values *LOCATION* and *ARTIFACT*

•   For *Artifactual Area* the DataProperty *hasConcreteEntityType* should take the values *ARTIFACTUAL_LOCATION* and *AREA*

[Class Tree & Class Descriptions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XIzd.png)

But after activating the reasoner, I get Artifactual Location misclassified to *Nothing*(but not both)

[Inference Explanations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FkjRO.jpg)

And I don't understand what's wrong with the inference explanation,but seems that there should be a third explanation like the second but related to the value *AREA*, so seems that doesn't support bi-valued properties like this, or, maybe there is another way to define and constraint the values of a multi-valued DataProperty or even the reasoner doesn't work fine with this,

**im using Hermit 1.3.8.3**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting the comment on my previous answer (I've deleted the answer because it is incorrect)

> [The ontology] should be here drive.google.com/file/d/0B2FYMQD3DD8DNWtteUlLcDgyTGM/ Look at the linguisticUnitType property for Morphosyntactic Unit, as I defined it (to have 2 values, MORPHOLOGICAL and SYNTACTIC) it is classified fine by the reasoner, but it doesn't behave the same with the properties hasConcreteEntityType and hasLocationType regarding the classes at Nothing Artifactual Area and Artifactual Location. I don't understand why for one case is fine but not for the other, because the properties and restrictions are defined in the same manner.

The problem is that `Artifactual Area` is defined as subclass of `Location`, which already restricts the values of `hasConcreteType` to only one value (`LOCATION`). In order to allow `Artifactual Area` to have exactly two values, the restriction on the superclass must be removed or amended.

For future reference, the fragment in Functional syntax is here:

```
Ontology(<http://localhost/pruebaLUO.owl>

DataPropertyDomain(:hasConcreteEntityType :ConcreteEntity)
DataPropertyRange(:hasConcreteEntityType DataOneOf("ARTIFACT"^^xsd:string "FOOD"^^xsd:string "LIVING_ENTITY"^^xsd:string "LOCATION"^^xsd:string "MATERIAL"^^xsd:string "ORGANIC_OBJECT"^^xsd:string "PHYSICAL_OBJECT"^^xsd:string "SUBSTANCE"^^xsd:string))

DataPropertyDomain(:hasLocationType :Location)
DataPropertyRange(:hasLocationType DataOneOf("3D"^^xsd:string "AREA"^^xsd:string "ARTIFACTUAL_LOCATION"^^xsd:string "GEOPOLITICAL"^^xsd:string "OPENING"^^xsd:string "OTHER"^^xsd:string))

DataPropertyDomain(:linguisticUnitType :LinguisticUnit)
DataPropertyRange(:linguisticUnitType DataOneOf("MORPHOLOGICAL"^^xsd:string "SEMANTIC"^^xsd:string "SYNTACTIC"^^xsd:string))

AnnotationAssertion(rdfs:label :Area "Area"@en)
SubClassOf(:Area :Location)
SubClassOf(:Area DataHasValue(:hasLocationType "AREA"^^xsd:string))

AnnotationAssertion(rdfs:label :Artifact "Artifact"@en)
SubClassOf(:Artifact :ConcreteEntity)
SubClassOf(:Artifact DataHasValue(:hasConcreteEntityType "ARTIFACT"^^xsd:string))

SubClassOf(:ArtifactualArea :Area)
SubClassOf(:ArtifactualArea :ArtifactualLocation)
SubClassOf(:ArtifactualArea DataExactCardinality(2 :hasLocationType DataOneOf("AREA"^^xsd:string "ARTIFACTUAL_ LOCATION"^^xsd:string)))

SubClassOf(:ArtifactualLocation :Artifact)
SubClassOf(:ArtifactualLocation :Location)
SubClassOf(:ArtifactualLocation DataHasValue(:hasLocationType "ARTIFACTUAL_ LOCATION"^^xsd:string))
SubClassOf(:ArtifactualLocation DataExactCardinality(2 :hasConcreteEntityType DataOneOf("ARTIFACT"^^xsd:string "LOCATION"^^xsd:string)))

SubClassOf(:Building :ArtifactualLocation)
SubClassOf(:ConcreteEntity :GenericEntity)
SubClassOf(:Entity :PropositionalComponent)
SubClassOf(:GenericEntity :Entity)
SubClassOf(:Location :ConcreteEntity)
SubClassOf(:Location DataHasValue(:hasConcreteEntityType "LOCATION"^^xsd:string))
SubClassOf(:MorphologicalUnit :LinguisticUnit)
SubClassOf(:MorphologicalUnit DataHasValue(:linguisticUnitType "MORPHOLOGICAL"^^xsd:string))
SubClassOf(:MorphosyntacticUnit :MorphologicalUnit)
SubClassOf(:MorphosyntacticUnit :Token)
SubClassOf(:MorphosyntacticUnit DataExactCardinality(2 :linguisticUnitType DataOneOf("MORPHOLOGICAL"^^xsd:string "SYNTACTIC"^^xsd:string)))
SubClassOf(:PropositionalComponent :SemanticUnit)
SubClassOf(:SemanticUnit :LinguisticUnit)
SubClassOf(:SemanticUnit DataHasValue(:linguisticUnitType "SEMANTIC"^^xsd:string))
SubClassOf(:SyntacticUnit :LinguisticUnit)
SubClassOf(:SyntacticUnit DataHasValue(:linguisticUnitType "SYNTACTIC"^^xsd:string))
SubClassOf(:Token :SyntacticUnit)
)
```

Comment: Ok may thanks, the Fragment in functional syntax posted doesn't have the restriction removed/ amended in case you wanted to post it with it as reference or just a reference to the problem.

Comment: Yes it was meant as a reference to the problem not the solution :-)

Comment: Ok, I think I have understood it.

Thank you very much.